# How to import my website to Kitsune

Tags: frameworks

I have been trying to import my website to kitsune platform. where do I find import tool in kitsune compiler? I have tried looking at the compiler but I could not find it but in release notes it was available.

Comment: Please provide more information, such as a link to the `release notes` you mention, source and target language(?) of `the compiler`, and what `import [a] website to kitsune platform` means, if that still is necessary.

Comment: Found that import tool on the compiler in this link http://compiler.kitsune.tools/. I was using wrong compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to https://dashboard.kitsune.tools/projects and login with your google account
2. Click on '+' icon on top right
3. If your website is already live, then provide the URL of the website for Kitsune to crawl and import all files of your website into a new project.
4. If you have the source code of the website, then create a new project, click on elipsis and click upload. You can now drag your root folder (of the source code) into the window. This would start the import process.